# Kendo Multiselect data.length undefined in template

Tags: templates, telerik, kendo-multiselect

This is very simple, I have a Multiselect and when one item is selected, I want the tag to represent the DataTextField.  When multiple items are selected, I want one tag to represent the quantity of items selected.  Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Placeholder("Select Employees...")
      .Name("empSelect")
      .DataTextField("Employee")
      .DataValueField("PERSONNEL_KEY")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;font-size:10px;", id = "empSelect" })
      .AutoBind(false)
      .AutoClose(false)
      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
      .TagTemplateId("tagTemplate")
      .DataSource(source => {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                 read.Action("GetEmployees", "EmployeeTS");
            })
      .ServerFiltering(true);}))
```

and here is the tagTemplate script:

```
<script id="tagTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
# if (data.length < 2) { #
    <span>
        #= data.Employee #
    </span>
# } else { #
    <span>
        #= data.length # selected
    </span>
# } #
```

All items come back from my Controller just fine. When I select an item(s), the tag displays "UNDEFINED selected".  Apparently "data.length" is undefined, yet I know of no other way to grab the count of items selected.

I am currently on the 2016.3.1118 build of Telerik Kendo MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"data" doesn't have property of length. Because of that, always works "else" and shows undefined.

```
<script>
function onChange(e) {
    var multi = $("#empSelect").data("kendoMultiSelect");

     var multi = $("#empSelect").data("kendoMultiSelect");

    if (multi.listView._dataItems.length > 1) {

        multi.setOptions({
            tagMode: 'single'
        });
    } else {
        multi.setOptions({
            tagMode: 'multiple'
        });
    }

    multi.refresh();
}
```

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
  .Placeholder("Select Employees...")
  .Name("empSelect")
  .DataTextField("TANIM")
  .DataValueField("URETIM_YERI")
  .AutoBind(false)
  .AutoClose(false)
  .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
  .TagMode(TagMode.Multiple)
  .Events(e =>
        {
            e.Change("onChange");
        })
  .DataSource(source =>
  {
      source.Read(read =>
      {
          read.Action("GetFactories", "Factory");
      })
.ServerFiltering(true);
  }))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So how do I grab the count of selected items?

Comment: If you don't want to show after first selection only item text, you can add ".TagMode(TagMode.Single)" and remove ".TagTemplateId("tagTemplate")"

Comment: I know that, but TagMode Single show's "1 Items(s) selected" when 1 item is selected.  I want it to show the DataTextField (Employee in this case) when 1 item is selected.  When multiple items are selected, I want it to show "{X} Item(s) selected"

Comment: All I need to do is replace "data.length" with whatever is required to grab the count of selected items and everything should work properly.

Comment: In the onChange event I added "multi.refresh()" to make it act correctly while deselecting items.  But overall, does the job.  Thanks!

Comment: your welcome :) @user2777664 I change the code with correct version.